# Why does not increase higher than number 2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to to display for each created user a rank (number).

frontend view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ngV.png

The backend code create for the first user the number 1 and for second number 2.
It should go on 3, 4, 5,...
But after number 2 it is not executing.

I am using java script for the backend, MongoDB for the data base and Mongoose for the User Schema.

```
    let ranks = 1
    higherRanks = ranks++
    
    const user = new User({
      rank: ranks,
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName, 

    });

    // rank validation

    const rankExist = await User.findOne({rank: ranks}); // search for existing rank
    // increase the rank (number) function
    if (rankExist){
      return new User({
      rank: higherRanks
    })
    }

    await user.save();

    res.json({
      successMessage:"user created",
      user: {
        _id: user._id,
        rank: user.rank,
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
      },
    });
```

The Question is why it not continue with number 3, 4, 5, ....?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ngV.png

Comment: You only ever set `higherRanks` once. If you need it to increment on the fly, you should probably define higherRanks as function.

Comment: Simply incrementing higherRanks here: `rank: higherRanks` should work too. Try `rank:higherRanks++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not moving to 3,4,5 is you have declared `let ranks = 1`
and `higherRanks = ranks++` this means that initially **rank is 1** and after increment it will be 2.Then you are creating user.

So, whenever you will be adding a new user it will word till 2.

To solve this you should add user first then increment it. Try this one:

```
  let ranks = 1;
const highRankUser = await User.findOne().sort({rank: -1});
if (highRankUser) {
  ranks = highRankUser.rank + 1;
}
const user = new User({
  rank: ranks,
  firstName: req.body.firstName,
  lastName: req.body.lastName, 
});
await user.save();
res.json({
  successMessage:"user created",
  user: {
    _id: user._id,
    rank: user.rank,
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
  },
});
```